# Working with the output of tapply() vs. ddply {plyr} in R: subsets of unequal length

Tags: r, subset, plyr

I have a dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(
+   Species = rep(LETTERS[1:4], times=c(5,6,7,6)),
+   Length = rep(11:14, each=3) 
+ )
> 
> df
```

I need to be able to count the number of individuals of a certain Length *for each Species* (i.e., how many individuals in Species A have a length of 1, 2, 3, etc?) Then, I need to perform a series of additional analyses on the output. For example, I need to calculate the density of individuals of each length, and the decrease in density from one length class to the next.

This is easy if I subset the data first:

```
Spec.A<-df[df$Species=="A",] 

#count number of specimens of each length; 
count<-table(Spec.A$Length)
count

#calculate density per length category (divide by total area sampled =30) 
density<-count/(30)
density

#calculate the decrease in density (delta.N) from one length category to the next; 
delta.N<-diff(density, lag=1, differences=1)
delta.N
```

The problem is that I need to do these calculations for each species (i.e., to loop through each subset).

On the one hand, I could use tapply(), with a function that uses table();

```
#function: count number of specimens of each length; 
count<-function(x){
table(x)
}

Number<-tapply(df$Length, df$Species, FUN=count, simplify=FALSE)
Number
```

This gives me what I want, but the format of the output is funky, and I can't figure out how to perform additional analyses on the results.

I have tried using ddply() from plyr, something like:

```
ddply(df$Length, df$Species,
count)
```

But I clearly don't have it right, and I'm not even sure ddply() is appropriate for my problem, given that I have a different number of length observations for each species.

Should I be looking more closely at other options in plyr? Or is there a way to write a *for* loop to do what I need?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but what I do suspect is that your first step should be to decide what _exactly_ you want your output to contain. Sketch a dataframe with column names and values with the information you want. That will probably give you (and us) some clues as to what to do.

Comment: @gkcn: Where does this data come from? Are you the OP?

Comment: @ThiefMaster it is the data from the original post, I had just printed it to see what exactly it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track! `tapply` with list output is definitely one way to go, and may be a good choice since your outputs will have varying lengths.

`ddply`, like you guessed, is another way. The key is that the output of the function you give to ddply should be a data frame with all your statistics in a "long" mode (so that they will stack nicely). The simple `count` function can't do this, so you'll need to make your own function. The way I go about devising a function for a ddply call like this is actually very similar to what you were doing: I get a subset of the data, and then craft my function using that. Then, when you submit it to ddply, it'll nicely apply that function across all the subsets.

```
SpeciesStats <- function(df) {
  counts    = table(df$Length)
  densities = counts/30
  delta.N   = diff(densities, lag=1, differences=1)

  data.frame(Length   = names(counts),
             Count    = as.numeric(counts),
             Density  = as.numeric(densities),
             delta.N  = c(NA, delta.N), 
             row.names=NULL)
}
```

```
> ddply(df, 'Species', SpeciesStats)
   Species Length Count    Density     delta.N
1        A     11     3 0.10000000          NA
2        A     12     2 0.06666667 -0.03333333
3        B     12     1 0.03333333          NA
4        B     13     3 0.10000000  0.06666667
5        B     14     2 0.06666667 -0.03333333
6        C     11     3 0.10000000          NA
7        C     12     3 0.10000000  0.00000000
8        C     14     1 0.03333333 -0.06666667
9        D     13     3 0.10000000          NA
10       D     14     3 0.10000000  0.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks John! This works great, and gives a nice clean output. It also connects some dots for me, in terms of how to set up functions to run through ddply...:)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a simpler way by using the `count` function in `plyr`

```
df1 <- ddply(df, .(Species, Length), count)
df2 <- ddply(df1, .(Species), mutate, Dens = freq/30, Del = diff(c(NA, Dens)))
```